# How can I get in a variable the message i have sent discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I need to send a message in the channel, and react to it, so I need to get that message to make a message.react

```
bot.sendMessage({
   to: channelID,
   message: '@everyone\n' + message.slice(16) + '\n\nCe message vise à demander quels jours vous pourriez être disponibles dans la semaine (de préférence le soir, vers 20h et alentours, pour un temps mentionné dans ce message). Réagissez donc sous ce message avec vos disponnibilités.\nJAAJ)'
});

message.react('')
   .then(() => message.react(''))
   .then(() => message.react(''))
   .then(() => message.react(''))
   .then(() => message.react(''))
   .then(() => message.react(''))
   .then(() => message.react(''))
```

Thanks for any answers ! :D

Comment: yes you are, its for voting if you can participate

Answer (score 0):

[`channel.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=send) returns a promise of a message, so you would use something like this:

```js
bot.channels.fetch(channelId).then(channel =>
  channel.send('message content here').then(message => {
    message.react('')
      .then(() => message.react(''))
       // rest of reactions
  })
)
```

Comment: ok, but how can i get the channel ? message.channel just tells me cannot read property send of undefined

Comment: @NoéMolmy Are you actually using `bot.sendMessage` to send your message? I [can't find a Client.sendMessage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?q=Client%23sendMessage) for v12 or v11 in the documentation.

Comment: well, i use channel.send (i want to) but i wanna send the message in another channel
i tried doing message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "test") but it tells me message.guild.channels.find is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you use discord v12. But better use ID for get a channel.

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name = 'test')
if (!channel) return console.log('can`t find a channel')

channel.send('SOME TEXT').then(msg => {
    msg.react('').then(() => msg.react('emojo').then(() => msg.react('emoji')))
})
```